# Change host details from localhost to server for Apache solr while moving to server

Tags: php, apache, solr, search-engine

Hi Team I have done a solr search module which is working in local machine. However when uploaded to server it is throwing Communication error in php page..

I am using code like this

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$limit = 1000;
 $query = isset($_REQUEST['q']) ? $_REQUEST['q']: false;
$results = false;

  $sdk=$_REQUEST['q'].$_REQUEST['fq'];


if ($query)
{

  require_once('Apache/Solr/Service.php');

  //changed from  $solr = new Apache_Solr_Service('localhost', 8180, '/solr/'); to

  $solr = new Apache_Solr_Service('index.websolr.com', 8180, '/solr/231sd3123');

  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1)
  {
 echo $query = stripslashes($query);
  }

  try
  {
    $results = $solr->search($query, 0, $limit);
  }
  catch (Exception $e)
  {
        die("<html><head><title>SEARCH EXCEPTION</title><body><pre>{$e->__toString()}</pre></body></html>");
  }
}

// display results
if ($results)
{
  $total = (int) $results->response->numFound;
  $start = min(1, $total);
  $end = min($limit, $total);
?>

 <?php
  // iterate result documents
  foreach ($results->response->docs as $doc)
  {

//getting objects by field names and their values then filtering to our requirment    
    foreach ($doc as $field => $value)
    { 
  if($field== "id")
{
    $id = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
    }
  if($field== "name")
{
    $name = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
    }
  if($field== "description")
{
    $description = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8');
    $des = $description; 
    }

     if($field== "level")
{
    $level = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
    }
  if($field== "download_link")
{
    $download_line = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
    }

 if($field== "source_code_link")
{
    $source_code_link = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
    }

   }

?>

<a href="codelisting.php?q=<?php echo $sdk; ?>&id=<?php echo $id; ?>&source=<?php echo $source_code_link; ?> "><p><?php echo $name ?></p></a>

<?php
  }
}
?>
```

Here is the part of Service.php to which is pointing out

```
protected function _sendRawGet($url, $timeout = FALSE)
    {
        $httpTransport = $this->getHttpTransport();

        $httpResponse = $httpTransport->performGetRequest($url, $timeout);
        $solrResponse = new Apache_Solr_Response($httpResponse, $this->_createDocuments, $this->_collapseSingleValueArrays);

        if ($solrResponse->getHttpStatus() != 200)
        {
            throw new Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException($solrResponse);
        }

        return $solrResponse;
    }
```

I dont where am I missing.. 
Any help appreciated...

Comment: Full error, especially line number would be useful, and is this the whole file?

Comment: Updated the above code..

Comment: exception 'Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException' with message ''0' Status: Communication Error' in /home/keystukc/public_html/amd/test1/Apache/Solr/Service.php:339